# Android PerodicWorkRequest stops running after a while

Tags: java, android

I have created an Android app with a Worker that reports the battery level of your phone to a remote server. The worker is registered in the main activities `OnCreate` like so

```java
PeriodicWorkRequest pwr = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(BatteryReportWorker.class,
        15, TimeUnit.MINUTES).setConstraints(
                new Constraints.Builder()
                        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                        .build())
        .build();
workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("BatteryReportWorker", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, pwr);
```

This works great for a little while, but at some point within less then a day the Worker stops sending reports to the backend. Simply opening the app and not doing anything instantly revives the worker and another report is sent instantly, which makes me think Android is just not running it anymore after a while. Why might Android stop running a periodic work request after a while? How would I even try and find out why it the work manager decided to stop running the worker?

A couple things I checked already:

- This is not an issue with Samsungs battery sleeping as it also happens on Google Pixel phones
- I'm also confident it is not the app pausing feature, since it takes less then a day for the app to stop sending reports

Comment: On which phone did you test this?

Comment: It maybe a problem with your network request.
Try to run a simple task to see if that result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

> WorkManager adheres to power-saving features and best practices like Doze mode, so you don't have to worry about it.

Starting from Android 6, Doze mode was introduced to save battery, which defers the background tasks until the next maintenance window or device being plugged or being used.

Follow [this](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby) to understand Doze mode.

Comment: I don't think that's it because even unlocking the phone does not revive the worker until you open the app