# PeriodicWork unreliability

Tags: android

The app responsibility is to change user wallpaper from the background task after selected time period passed.

I expected a periodic job to be executed at semi-regular intervals until cancelled.

While testing it on a couple phones I noticed after some time, the job stopped executing.
However when I opened the app (without rescheduling job) and returned to launcher screen, wallpaper changed.

What can cause such behavior? I thought the job will run for certain after time period expired and the doze mode was exited.
I don't use any worker constraints.

Info:

- $period />= 15m
- worker class: CoroutineWorker
- job scheduling code:

```
            val work = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<ChangeWallpaperWorker>(period, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .setInputData(data)
            if (!binding.changeNow.isChecked)
                work.setInitialDelay(period, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(requireContext())
            workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                WALLPAPER_WORK_TAG,
                ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, 
                work.build()
            )
```

I found a similar problem, but unfortunately without an answer: [Android PerodicWorkRequest stops running after a while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74341700/android-perodicworkrequest-stops-running-after-a-while)